# Photoshop showing Black where shades of blue should be

Tags: adobe-photoshop, colors, graphics

Photoshop is showing black where colors should be. I assume this must be a graphics issue, but I'm on the latest graphics card driver (I have a Radeon 7870), and I believe Photoshop is updated as much as possible. I cleared my settings with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> on startup, but no luck.

How can I fix this issue?

Photoshop showing it wrong:
[image: 1]

Photoshop save for web, showing it right:
[image: 2]

**Edit**: *Updating my drivers fixed the issue.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a driver issue. I have a Radeon HD 7870 as well and the problem only started appearing since the latest driver update. Rolling back the driver fixed the problem for me.

(Random side note: it's any color with red component equal to 0 that is rendered black.)